# How to remove VLRs from header?

Tags: c++, pdal

I want to create a .las file without any VLR using pdal.
Apparently, two VLR are automatically created by the writer.
That happens even with the las writer option "pdal_metadata" set to false.

Using the command `pdal info --metadata <file>`, I can see two VLRs automatically created: vlr_0, and vlr_1.

```
"vlr_0":
    {
      "data": "UF(This field was changed to save space)jMyNjMzIl1dAA==",
      "description": "OGC Transformation Record",
      "record_id": 2112,
      "user_id": "LASF_Projection"
    },
"vlr_1":
   {
     "data": "UFJlTWyJFY(This field was changed to save space)yIsIjMyNjMzIl1dAA==",
     "description": "OGR variant of OpenGIS WKT SRS",
     "record_id": 2112,
     "user_id": "liblas"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these VLRs are for storing coordinate system information about the file. To have these removed, you will need to set `readers.las.nosrs=true` when reading your data to cause your pipeline(s) to have no SRS information.

Note that you probably do not want that.